# How to prevent System.getProperty("user.name") from being spoofed

Tags: java, java-security

I am building a desktop app in java where I need the logged in username .
I am using `System.getProperty("user.name")` to get the username.

But this can be spoofed by using

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
    p.put("user.name", "XYZ");
    System.setProperties(p);
```

or by

```
-Duser.name=someothername
```

How can I prevent this spoofing or any alternative to get logged in username in a secure way.
The desktop application is platform independent.

Comment: How do you authenticate the user?
You can only be sure that its a valid user, after authetication was successful.

Comment: There is mechanism to authenticate the user. The problem is the app will run on shared machine and there can be a situation where the users who have logged in are the authenticated users. since the System.getProperty("user.name") can be spoofed we want prevent any mishandling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System properties are not environment variables. Use `System.getenv("USERNAME")` for environment variables. `System.properties` can still be set by user on java command line with `java -Duser.name=someoneelse`.

Comment: Environment variables can also be set before running the program, in a manner way easier than tweaking system properties...